# How to get all children of a subArray in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So here's my problem:

So this is what my array looks like, I have shown a fragment of it here (from the console window).

[image: Array]

It's overall pretty basic right? Except for it's indexing. As you see the first has value `"1"` and let's say the second has value `"4"`. As for it's subarrays, these have custom indexes too.

Therefore, the old fashioned:

```
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  someVar = array[i];
  //do something
}
```

won't work.

I get the 1 or 4 from iterating through another array, so don't need to get those.

I want to get all subArrays(not the further nested subArrays, only the second level).

So basicly what I want is something like this(is there something like this?):

```
array[someIndex].children.forEach(
  //do something with **this**
)
```

To make it more practical for you: 
So I know that the first array has `index 1`. How can I get the values of `cat1` and `cat2` without knowing it has `index 2` (this could also be `6` or `42` for example). In this case, the first array only has one subArray but I would like to make it work for multiple subArrays. (to clarify, select `cat1`, `cat2` from the second level subarray with, in this case, `index 2`)

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Evoc

Comment: *"it might be not quite correct because I only made this one for the example but I hope you can work with it"* Not really. In JavaScript, you define an **array** using `[entry0, entry1, entry2]`. (E.g., `[1, 2, 3]` or `["a", "b", "c"]` or `[1, "b", 32.4]`, etc.) You define an **object** with `{key1: value1, key2: value2}`. So please update your question using correct array vs. object notation; otherwise, people will have to guess.

Comment: please add the array with the keys as well.

Comment: You said you only wanted the non-numerical properties in the second level, right?  Well `msg1` is in the third level, so what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Looks like a array with `length = 1` with nested properties.

Comment: Allright, I'll completely update my question, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I have changed it! I hope it's all clear now :). Again, sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't arrays. You have

```
[   {   "1": { etc...
```

which is an array containing an object containing multiple other objects. You can't really use a `for(i=...)` loop for this, because your keys aren't sequential. You should use a `for ... in` loop instead:

```
arr = [{"1":{....}}];

for (i in arr[0]) {
   for (j in arr[0][i]) {
       console.log(arr[0][i][j]['msg']);
   }
}
```

Comment: Technically he does have an array although probably not intended to be used in that fashion.

Comment: Be aware `for in` does not guarantee any order of iteration.

Comment: Thanks @marc, I did get the array wrong... My bad, I'm sorry for that. Ps. this is one level too far but I get the point :p

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to get the properties ordered with the integer indices first, from smallest to greatest. Iterate them to get `msg1`.

```js
var array = {"1":{"3":{"5":{"data":"someData","moreData":"someMoreData"},"msg1":"hello world","msg2":"foo equals bar"},"5":{"8":{"data":"someData","moreData":"someMoreData"},"msg1":"world hello","msg2":"bar equals foo"},"your_name":"jimmy","your_msg":"hello world"},"4":{"3":{"5":{"data":"someData","moreData":"someMoreData"},"msg1":"hello world","msg2":"foo equals bar"},"5":{"8":{"data":"someData","moreData":"someMoreData"},"msg1":"world hello","msg2":"bar equals foo"},"your_name":"billy","your_msg":"foo equals bar"}};
for(let key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array[1])) {
  if(Object(array[1][key]) !== array[1][key]) break;
  console.log('msg1 of "'+key+'": ' + array[1][key].msg1);
}
console.log('your_msg: ' + array[1].your_msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you showed it's an array with only one index, inside of this index there are nested objects, you could iterate them using the property iterator (foreach). You have to go to the second level tho, since the values you need are there.

```
for (var key in object) {
    for(var anotherKey in object[key]) {
        //check for undefined 
        if(object[key][anotherKey].hasOwnProperty('msg')) {
            //code
        }

    }
}
```

{ } - declaring objects (literal)

[ ] - declaring arrays